# Use Form1's last record's ID value to create new record in Table2 to be used by Form2 with the ID value in the related field linking both forms

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have student applications with more than 300 fields. I have to split those fields between several tables such as tContacts, tHousehold, tMobilityAids, etc.

My first form: fContacts is used to to begin the long process of applying. Data is recieved in chunks over several weeks. fContacts generates a unique IDContact for every potential student but only creates a record in tContacts.

I'd like to create a matching related  record in tHousehold as the fContacts form closes. I'd like the tContacts[IDContact](key, autonumber) to be placed in the second column of a new record in tHousehold, using a field called ContactID.

I later use a non-editing form to display tabs of all tables holding application data. I look for blanks to prompt me for who I need to follow up with. If I don't have data to enter into the fHousehold form right after I fill out the fContacts form, then tHousehold doesn't create a matching record and my tabs in the third form (fReviewApplicationData) do not update when choosing a different student in a combobox. I still see data from the last tHousehold record displaying. Not useful and potentially misleading.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you're closing fContacts form, either create a new record for fHousehold using INSERT and assign the fContacts!ID to that record.  Or if you're using a form, open the form and set the IDContact field in the form on Open or Load.

Comment: That sounds like the path forward. I will try that, thank you. I was stuck on trying an IF ELSE strategy. I am not a formally trained programmer and often find myself in blind alleys